# Add Helm Hub as a remote repository on Artifactory

Tags: kubernetes, artifactory, kubernetes-helm

I have been serving Helm Stable as a remote repository in Artifactory for a few months now with no issue, however one of the charts I use has recently moved on to Helm hub. Try as I may, I cannot seem to get Artifactory to recognise this as a remote repo.I have tried adding both https://hub.helm.sh/ and https://charts.jetstack.io (The chart in question is Jetstack's cert-manager) to no avail. It just shows up as empty in Artifactory.

Does anyone have any experience getting Artifactory remote repos working with Helm Hub?

Comment: which chart you're using?

Comment: jetstack/cert-manager  v0.7.0

Comment: So, you want to install `jetstack/cert-manager v0.7.0`?

Comment: Yes that is what i said

Comment: I'm assuming you were just trying to get your post count up. Anyone else?

Answer (score 2):

In Artifactory, to create a remote Helm repository for https://charts.jetstack.io content, "Bypass HEAD Requests" in the advanced settings must be enabled. This is because Artifactory first makes a HEAD request for /index.yaml, to which charts.jetstack.io responds with a 404:

```
$ curl -siXHEAD https://charts.jetstack.io/index.yaml
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.15.6
...
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `jetstack` repo with below command.

```
helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io
```

if this helm repo is already added, we can update with

```
helm update
```

then if you run `helm search jetstack` you'll find your chart as below:

```
NAME                    CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION
jetstack/cert-manager   v0.7.0          v0.7.0      A Helm chart for cert-manager
jetstack/tor-proxy      0.1.1                       A Helm chart for Kubernetes
```

### Note

- For successful deployment, you should install CRDs before **helm install**

```
kubectl apply \
   -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jetstack/cert-manager/release-0.7/deploy/manifests/00-crds.yaml
```

- If you're installing helm chart in some **XX** namespace which is already existed, you should label this **XX** namespace with `certmanager.k8s.io/disable-validation="true"`

```
kubectl label namespace XX certmanager.k8s.io/disable-validation="true"
```

### Last

to install run below command
`helm install --name my-release --namespace XX jetstack/cert-manager`

Comment: This in no ways help solve the problem and was not was the OP was asking for.